# Using twilio flex, how do I create warm transfer with external phone (not an agent, or queue)

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

I see that out of the box (v<=1.11) twilio flex allows warm transfers to either

- Agents
- Queues

Im interested in expanding this such that I can add external phone numbers to a list/set and engage with the external party from the UI perspective similar to the way I engage with the Agents/Queues. Said another way, I would like to allow warm transfers to

- Agents
- Queues
- External Contacts (NEW)

I'm hoping the warm transfer to an external phone number can have a similar experience as shown here
https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/warm-transfer-end-user-guide

What customization options are available in order for me to add this type of functionality? Where would I begin?

I would imagine that many other businesses that use flex have a strong use case to do warm transfers to external phone numbers while using the flex UI. Perhaps to people who are using other types of systems, and are located within an entirely different company. How might they be accomplishing this use case?

Is the 'warm transfer' experience exclusive to transfers that are happening to Agents/Queues only? I hope not.

Any help/guidence is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

UPDATE: 
Answered my own question below. Next step for me is to figure out how to obtain the conferenceSid upon reserving voice task. Ive created separate question for that

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I can simply use the voice api to add a participant as follows(C# library is 1 way)

```
            const string accountSid = "11";
        const string authToken = "11";

        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

        var participant = ParticipantResource.Create(
            from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("+1XXX"),
            to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("+1XXX"),
            pathConferenceSid: "XXX"
        );
```